# Can't draw more complex scene using XNA 4.0 and windows forms

Tags: c#, winforms, xna

I have tried this code sample by Microsoft which allows you to use a custom Windows Forms Control to draw an XNA GS 4.0 scene:

[winforms series 1](http://create.msdn.com/en-US/education/catalog/sample/winforms_series_1).

The code works great when drawing a single triangle, but when i try to draw a generated mesh it just draws X in the control.
I debugged the code and it seems that when i reach:

```
  graphics.GraphicsDevice.DrawUserIndexedPrimitives<VertexPositionColor>(PrimitiveType.TriangleList, Vertices, 0, Vertices.Length, indicies, 0, indicies.Length / 3);
```

It never exits the Draw function.
I have tested my code in a normal XNA Game Project and it works 100%.

Does anyone have a clue what's going on?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I'm confused.  If your code runs fine in an XNA Game Project then what is the issue?  I would think that an XNA Game Project is better suited for turning a poly object into a graphic object then a simple form created for the purposes of a simple tutorial.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it seems that the problem was the XNA reach profile, Just changed it to hiDef and it worked ! :)